# How to Get Nodes from XML that has Namespaces

Tags: xml, vba, xpath

got a xml with Namespaces. Problem is i didnt get any Nodes. (Except with *) Searching several Sites and posts about the right syntax...nothing worked. Down below my xml and my code in vba. What am i doing wrong with these namespaces plz help. With //@NodeId i get the Attributes i want, but this is not enough i need the Node.... i didnt even get the first one (UANodeSet) xmlNodes says = Nothing.... any help would be nice

```
    xmlDoc.Load Application.GetOpenFilename()
    xmlDoc.setProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath"
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    oTarget.Parent.EnableCalculation = False
    
    XmlNamespaces = "xmlns:ua='http://xxx/NodeSet.xsd'"
    xmlDoc.setProperty "SelectionNamespaces", XmlNamespaces
    Set xmlNodes = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("/ua:UANodeSet/ua:UAVariable)
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<UANodeSet xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:uax="http://opcfoundation.org/UA/2008/02/Types.xsd" xmlns:ua="http://xxx/NodeSet.xsd" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:pv="xxx/PV.xsd" xmlns="http://opcfoundation.org/UA/2011/03/UANodeSet.xsd">
    <UAVariable DataType="ns=1;i=100040" ParentNodeId="ns=1;s=::AsGlobalPV:gLebewesen.Tier.Hund" NodeId="ns=1;s=::AsGlobalPV:gLebewesen.Tier.Hund[0]" BrowseName="1:Hund[0]" AccessLevel="3" ValueRank="-1">
        <DisplayName>Hund[0]</DisplayName>
        <References>
            <Reference ReferenceType="HasTypeDefinition">ns=1;i=100045</Reference>
            <Reference ReferenceType="HasComponent">ns=1;s=::AsGlobalPV:gLebewesen.Tier.Hund[0].Xoloitzcuintli</Reference>
            <Reference ReferenceType="HasComponent">ns=1;s=::AsGlobalPV:gLebewesen.Tier.Hund[0].MastinoNapoletano</Reference>
        </References>
        <Extensions>
            <Extension>
                <pv:VariableExtension AuditEvents="true">
                    <Value>
                        <Binding Type="PV" Target="::gLebewesen.Tier.Hund[0]"/>
                    </Value>
                </pv:VariableExtension>
            </Extension>
        </Extensions>
    </UAVariable>
    <UAVariable DataType="i=1" ParentNodeId="ns=1;s=::AsGlobalPV:gLebewesen.Tier.Hund[0]" NodeId="ns=1;s=::AsGlobalPV:gLebewesen.Tier.Hund[0].Xoloitzcuintli" BrowseName="1:Xoloitzcuintli" AccessLevel="3" ValueRank="1" ArrayDimensions="2">
        <DisplayName>Xoloitzcuintli</DisplayName>
        <References>
            <Reference ReferenceType="HasComponent">ns=1;s=::AsGlobalPV:gLebewesen.Tier.Hund[0].Xoloitzcuintli[0]</Reference>
            <Reference ReferenceType="HasComponent">ns=1;s=::AsGlobalPV:gLebewesen.Tier.Hund[0].Xoloitzcuintli[1]</Reference>
        </References>
        <Extensions>
            <Extension>
                <pv:VariableExtension AuditEvents="true">
                    <Value>
                        <Binding Type="PV" Target="::gLebewesen.Tier.Hund[0].Xoloitzcuintli"/>
                    </Value>
                </pv:VariableExtension>
            </Extension>
        </Extensions>
    </UAVariable>
    <UAVariable DataType="i=1" ParentNodeId="ns=1;s=::AsGlobalPV:gLebewesen.Tier.Hund[0].Xoloitzcuintli" NodeId="ns=1;s=::AsGlobalPV:gLebewesen.Tier.Hund[0].Xoloitzcuintli[0]" BrowseName="1:Xoloitzcuintli[0]" AccessLevel="3">
        <DisplayName>Xoloitzcuintli[0]</DisplayName>
        <Extensions>
            <Extension>
                <pv:VariableExtension AuditEvents="true">
                    <ACL>
                        <ACE Role="1" Allow="0x017F"/>
                        <ACE Role="2" Allow="0x015F"/>
                    </ACL>
                    <Value>
                        <Binding Type="PV" Target="::gLebewesen.Tier.Hund[0].Xoloitzcuintli[0]"/>
                    </Value>
                </pv:VariableExtension>
            </Extension>
        </Extensions>
    </UAVariable>
    <UAVariable DataType="i=1" ParentNodeId="ns=1;s=::AsGlobalPV:gLebewesen.Tier.Hund[0].Xoloitzcuintli" NodeId="ns=1;s=::AsGlobalPV:gLebewesen.Tier.Hund[0].Xoloitzcuintli[1]" BrowseName="1:Xoloitzcuintli[1]" AccessLevel="3">
        <DisplayName>Xoloitzcuintli[1]</DisplayName>
        <Extensions>
            <Extension>
                <pv:VariableExtension AuditEvents="true">
                    <ACL>
                        <ACE Role="1" Allow="0x017F"/>
                        <ACE Role="2" Allow="0x015F"/>
                    </ACL>
                    <Value>
                        <Binding Type="PV" Target="::gLebewesen.Tier.Hund[0].Xoloitzcuintli[1]"/>
                    </Value>
                </pv:VariableExtension>
            </Extension>
        </Extensions>
    </UAVariable>
    <UAVariable DataType="i=7" ParentNodeId="ns=1;s=::AsGlobalPV:gLebewesen.Tier.Hund[0]" NodeId="ns=1;s=::AsGlobalPV:gLebewesen.Tier.Hund[0].MastinoNapoletano" BrowseName="1:MastinoNapoletano" AccessLevel="3">
        <DisplayName>MastinoNapoletano</DisplayName>
        <References>
            <Reference ReferenceType="HasTypeDefinition">i=63</Reference>
        </References>
        <Extensions>
            <Extension>
                <pv:VariableExtension AuditEvents="true">
                    <Value>
                        <Binding Type="PV" Target="::gLebewesen.Tier.Hund[0].MastinoNapoletano"/>
                    </Value>
                </pv:VariableExtension>
            </Extension>
        </Extensions>
    </UAVariable>
    <UAVariable DataType="ns=1;i=100040" ParentNodeId="ns=1;s=::AsGlobalPV:gLebewesen.Tier.Hund" NodeId="ns=1;s=::AsGlobalPV:gLebewesen.Tier.Hund[1]" BrowseName="1:Hund[1]" AccessLevel="3" ValueRank="-1">
        <DisplayName>Hund[1]</DisplayName>
        <References>
            <Reference ReferenceType="HasTypeDefinition">ns=1;i=100045</Reference>
            <Reference ReferenceType="HasComponent">ns=1;s=::AsGlobalPV:gLebewesen.Tier.Hund[1].Xoloitzcuintli</Reference>
            <Reference ReferenceType="HasComponent">ns=1;s=::AsGlobalPV:gLebewesen.Tier.Hund[1].MastinoNapoletano</Reference>
        </References>
        <Extensions>
            <Extension>
                <pv:VariableExtension AuditEvents="true">
                    <Value>
                        <Binding Type="PV" Target="::gLebewesen.Tier.Hund[1]"/>
                    </Value>
                </pv:VariableExtension>
            </Extension>
        </Extensions>
    </UAVariable>
    <UAVariable DataType="i=1" ParentNodeId="ns=1;s=::AsGlobalPV:gLebewesen.Tier.Hund[1]" NodeId="ns=1;s=::AsGlobalPV:gLebewesen.Tier.Hund[1].Xoloitzcuintli" BrowseName="1:Xoloitzcuintli" AccessLevel="3" ValueRank="1" ArrayDimensions="2">
        <DisplayName>Xoloitzcuintli</DisplayName>
        <Extensions>
            <Extension>
                <pv:VariableExtension AuditEvents="true">
                    <ACL>
                        <ACE Role="1" Allow="0x017F"/>
                        <ACE Role="2" Allow="0x015F"/>
                    </ACL>
                    <Value>
                        <Binding Type="PV" Target="::gLebewesen.Tier.Hund[1].Xoloitzcuintli"/>
                    </Value>
                </pv:VariableExtension>
            </Extension>
        </Extensions>
    </UAVariable>
    <UAVariable DataType="i=7" ParentNodeId="ns=1;s=::AsGlobalPV:gLebewesen.Tier.Hund[1]" NodeId="ns=1;s=::AsGlobalPV:gLebewesen.Tier.Hund[1].MastinoNapoletano" BrowseName="1:MastinoNapoletano" AccessLevel="3">
        <DisplayName>MastinoNapoletano</DisplayName>
        <References>
            <Reference ReferenceType="HasTypeDefinition">i=63</Reference>
        </References>
        <Extensions>
            <Extension>
                <pv:VariableExtension AuditEvents="true">
                    <Value>
                        <Binding Type="PV" Target="::gLebewesen.Tier.Hund[1].MastinoNapoletano"/>
                    </Value>
                </pv:VariableExtension>
            </Extension>
        </Extensions>
    </UAVariable>
</UANodeSet>
```

Comment: Did you try to mask any part of the namespace? Anyway, the namespace in the XML and in your property need to match exactly, in the XML you have posted you show us `xmlns:ua="XXX/NodeSet.xsd"` while the VBA code has `xmlns:ua='http://xxx/NodeSet.xsd'` so the VBA has a prefix `http://` you don't show in the XML and furthermore the `xxx` in the XML is in upper case while the VBA has lower case. Whatever case and exact name the namespace has in the XML, you need to use exactly that name in VBA as well.

Comment: Ok i edited this namespace wrong its not the original namespace, cause im not allowed to show the original link. in my code theyre the same.

Comment: Consider to post minimal but complete samples to allow others to reproduce the problem. SelectNodes can't return Nothing as it returns a IXMLDOMNodeList. Have you set the `async` property of the `xmlDoc` property to `False`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main issue is not registering the default namespace. Your XML contains multiple namespaces with prefixes and one without a prefix:

With prefixes:

```
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:uax="http://opcfoundation.org/UA/2008/02/Types.xsd" 
xmlns:ua="http://xxx/NodeSet.xsd" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns:pv="xxx/PV.xsd"
```

Without prefix:

```
xmlns="http://opcfoundation.org/UA/2011/03/UANodeSet.xsd"
```

The namespace without prefix is considered the default namespace and all underlying nodes in document will fall under this namespace if nodes do not maintain a prefix. Since `<UANodeSet>` and `<UAVariable>` do not have a colon-separated prefix (unlike `<pv:VariableExtension>`), you must parse their content under this default namespace in VBA.

Below registers all namespaces and the default namespace with a user-defined name, `sonic`, which will be used in XPath parsing. Note: namespaces are combined in a space-separated string.

```vb
XmlNamespaces = "xmlns:sonic='http://opcfoundation.org/UA/2011/03/UANodeSet.xsd' " & _    
                "xmlns:ua='http://xxx/NodeSet.xsd' " & _      
                "xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' "  & _                   
                "xmlns:uax='http://opcfoundation.org/UA/2008/02/Types.xsd' " & _
                "xmlns:ua='http://xxx/NodeSet.xsd' " & _ 
                "xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' " & _ 
                "xmlns:pv='xxx/PV.xsd'" 

xmlDoc.setProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath"
xmlDoc.setProperty "SelectionNamespaces", XmlNamespaces

Set xmlNodes = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("/sonic:UANodeSet/sonic:UAVariable")
```

Comment: Thank you very much exactly what i needed.

Comment: Great to hear and glad to help! Happy coding!